# Create view that shows all objects relating to current user's department

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have the following Django model:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Appeal(models.Model):

    DEPARTMENTS = [
        ("a", "DeptA"),
        ("b", "DeptB"),
        ("c", "DeptC"),
        # long list of departments here
    ]

    title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    department = models.CharField(choices=DEPARTMENTS)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="appeals"
    )
```

And a view like this:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404, render

def appeal_list_view(request):
    visible_appeals = get_list_or_404(Appeal, author=request.user)
    return render(request, "appeals/index.html", {"appeals": visible_appeals})
```

This shows only the appeals by the current user. I would like to change this code so that:

- each user is associated with a department,
- a user is shown all appeals from their own department (regardless of whether or not they or another user from the same department submitted it).

What would be the best way to achieve this? I considered creating a group per department, which would solve the first requirement but then I'm not sure how to approach the second one.

Comment: Can you add a `Department` model, the `choices` really doesn't look like a good idea both in modeling and performance.

Comment: Fair point, thanks. I'll change that.

Comment: Can you share the user model (or do you use the builtin one)? This might help to provide a helpful answer.

Comment: I started out with the built-in one but after @ebram-shehata's answer, I changed it to the simplest possible custom model.

Comment: can a user belong to *one* department, or *multiple* ones?

Comment: Each user belongs to exactly one department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Assuming that your user model has a field named `department` that represents user's department.. you can update your query to something like:

```
visible_appeals = get_list_or_404(Appeal, author__department=request.user.department)
```